# Suppose I have 5 directories how do I push only 4 directories to git and leave the 5th one?

Tags: git, github

Suppose I have 5 directories how do I push only 4 directories to git and leave the 5th one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the name of the directory you do not want committed in a .gitignore file in the root of your repository.